# How to document settings method with phpdoc

Tags: php, oop, phpdoc

I have a class with the methods `getSetting($name)` and `setSetting($name,$value)`. These methods are used to set multiple settings throughout the class.

My question is what is the best way in `phpDoc` to document the available settings. I cannot do it above these methods i think, because the methods are defined only in the parent class and the children might have their own settings.

My first guess was to document it above each class in the description, so like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * A tomato class. Needed for pizza
 * 
 * Settings:
 * color string default: red
 * size integer
 */
 class tomato extends fruit{
    function __construct(){
        $this->setSetting('color','red');
    }
 }

 /**
 * A fruit class
 *
 * Settings:
 * price integer
 */

 class fruit{
    var $settings   = array();
    /**
     * Sets setting
     * @param string $name
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    function setSetting($name,$value = NULL){
        $this->settings[$name]  = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns setting
     * @param string $name
     * @return mixed
     */
    function getSetting($name){
        if(isset($this->settings[$name])){
            return $this->settings[$name];
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
 }


 ?>
```

I was wondering if this was correct, or if there might be tags available for this, or maybe an other better solution.

Comment: First of all, as i see, the color red is a string, not an int :) But anyway, if you have a `private $color` then define it, and add php doc to it. If it's inherited, then does not matter, because when you create the php doc, it will show, what is the parent class.

Comment: Yes, that is why i put string after color, Size is another setting. And i don't have a private $color, since it will be stored in an array.

i know how to document vars, but that is not the case here.